# Xcode Memory Graph - showing increasing memory use - what exactly does it show?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode-instruments

When watching the debug graph in xcode 6 (and probably 5 too), when running my application the memory use continues to rise as I place more of a certain object on the screen and animate it's movement. It does not seem to decrease when I remove it. Once removed I believe there are no more references to them.

See screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnhbK.png

However when I use Instruments to try to identify what's going on, there's only around 12mb persisting, and Total Bytes continues to rise, as expected.

See screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBwce.png

Is this normal behaviour? What exactly is the graph in Xcode showing? Am I overlooking something?

In Instruments I have Allocation Lifespan set to All Allocations and Allocation Type set to All Heap and Anonymous VM for the screenshots above.

**UPDATE**

By running Instruments with Activity Monitor I was able to see that the "Real Memory" was increasing at the same rate as is displayed in Xcode. @Mark Szymczyk pointed out that OpenGL ES Texture memory allocations are not shown in the Allocations instrument.

By purging the texture cache with the following command in Cocos2D 3.1 at regular intervals, memory use consistently drops back down to around 18mb and begins increasing again as I add more sprites.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
```

Credits go to Mark Szymczyk for pointing me in this direction - thanks!

Comment: Hi JoGoFo, Have you enabled Zombie in your project?

Comment: Hey Student, I meant to mention that Zombie is turned off. Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi, Are you using large collection of images in your project ?

Comment: Not a large amount of images, no. Less than 10. I'm more curious to know if I'm looking at this correctly or if I'm missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at your screenshots, the Xcode graph is probably showing the equivalent of the Total Bytes column in your Instruments screenshot. When you remove an object, the persistent bytes will decrease, but the total bytes won't. That would explain why the memory use never goes down in the Xcode graph.

The Persistent Bytes column in Instruments is what you should be looking at to determine your app's memory usage.

Comment: Thanks Mark. This is what I gathered, but is anyone able to confirm that this is what the Xcode graph is showing?

I also wondered if Xcode was maybe showing allocated blocks of memory, and perhaps I have some kind of fragmentation issue?

Comment: The Allocations instrument doesn't record OpenGL ES texture allocations. Xcode's memory graph could be showing texture memory allocations that the Allocations instrument won't show.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this was exactly what the problem was. Purging my texture cache at regular intervals fixes this. I will update my question with more details and accept your answer - thanks again!

Comment: @MarkSzymczyk I don't think it's correct to say that the Xcode gauge graph is showing total bytes. I wasn't able to find official documentation, but that value nearly always matches the values seen in Activity Monitor's current total Memory column. Pointing out the fact that Instruments doesn't show OpenGL ES textures sounds like a more reasonably correct answer. But right now I think this answer is misleading.