# Memory result from Xcode is different to Instrument

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, memory-leaks, instruments

I am trying to see how much memory my program uses and identify leaks. I have tried looking at the memory page built into xcode and also the Allocation instrument. They get totally different result though (Both simulated on my 6s).

An outline of what I did...
I have a tableview that loads images from firebase. My test was keep pressing "reload all data" button at 3 second interval for a bit (30 seconds) and observe how the memory reflects what I did. Below are the results of the two screen shots.

What is weird is that for xcode result, I see that my memory just continues to climb higher and higher upon every refresh (Which suggests that I have a leak somewhere as the table view should discard the original data and load new ones. So I would expect highs and lows). So I went into the allocation instrument and did the same test. However, what I instead see is that the total persistent byte doesnt grow as crazy as before and remains hovering around 23.36mb with minor highs and lows (As what I might expect for reloading a table?)

Any explanations?

-- Update--
The answer here appears to contradict to what I believe is right
[Xcode Memory Graph - showing increasing memory use - what exactly does it show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26273361/xcode-memory-graph-showing-increasing-memory-use-what-exactly-does-it-show)

Because I have tried hitting the refresh button for an hour to let the memory build up to nearly 1.5GB and I did get a memory warning. So I dont believe Xcode is showing "total bytes".

[image: memory differnece]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the huge difference between XCode & instruments memory usage, and is it ok?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822679/why-the-huge-difference-between-xcode-instruments-memory-usage-and-is-it-ok)